# How to connect to wifi from command line?

Tags: debian, wifi, kali-linux

I'm using latest version of Debian-based Linux Kali.  Maybe it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as the main problem is after I log in to the system I get a blank screen and mouse pointer. Somebody on the Internet recommend me to change window manager.

But I'm unable to do this as I can't connect to wifi.

I found tutorial how to do this [here](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/18/connect-to-wifi-network-from-command-line-in-linux/)

And I tried to do it step by step, but it doesn't work for me.
In that tutorial that author wrote that I need use the command `ip link set wlan0 ip` to bring up the wifi interface. In his example the output looks like this:

```
root@kali:~# ip link show w
lan0 4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT qlen 1000
  link/ether 00:60:64:37:4a:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

root@kali:~# ip link set wlan0 up

root@kali:~# ip link show wlan0
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:64:37:4a:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

On the other hand when I call:

```
   ip link set wlan0 up
   ip link show wlan0
```

I get:

```
  4: wlan0: <NO_CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:60:64:37:4a:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and after running wpa supplicant with valid network details

```
wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`iw wlan0 link` still returns `Not connected.`

How do I solve this problem and what shall I do next?

Comment: Can you scan using `iwlist scan` ?

Comment: @GAD3R yes i can

Comment: some are different: so i used;
`ifup wlp1s0` to bring the network up and `ifdown wlp1s0` to bring it down.

Comment: Kali has wifi disabled by default.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm assuming `wpa_supplicant` and `iw` is installed.

1. To connect to wifi through `wpa_supplicant`
   you need to create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file

   ```
   nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```

   with the following lines:

   ```
   network={
            ssid="wifi_name"
            psk="wifi_key"
   }
   ```

Or you can use `wpa_passphrase` to create the configuration file (copy and past):

```
wpa_passphrase "Your_SSID" Your_passwd
```

Also you can write the `wpa_supplicant.conf` directly through:

```
wpa_passphrase "Your_SSID" Your_passwd > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

to connect type the following command:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211,wext
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

> [Note](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#nl80211_driver_not_supported_on_some_hardware): Multiple comma separated driver wrappers in option `-Dnl80211,wext` makes wpa_supplicant use the first driver wrapper that is able to initialize the interface (see wpa_supplicant(8)). This is useful when using mutiple or removable (e.g. USB) wireless devices which use different drivers.

You can connect through `wpa_supplicant` without `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "Your_SSID" Your_passphrase) && dhclient wlan0
```

You can visit the official [documentation of Arch-linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant)  to get more information about the configuration file and arguments.

2. you can connect through `nmcli`

   ```
   nmcli d wifi connect Your_SSID password Your_Psswd_here ifname Your_interface
   ```

Example:

```
nmcli d wifi connect MYSSID password 12345678 ifname wlan0
```

3. Also you can connect through `wpa_cli`:

Open the terminal and type `wpa_cli`

To scan, type:

```
scan
scan_results
```

Create a network:

```
add_network
```

This will output a number, which is the network ID, for example `0`
Next, we need to set the SSID and PSK for the network.

```
set_network 0 ssid "SSID_here"
set_network 0 psk "Passphrase_here"
```

Once the wireless has connected, it should automatically get an IP address.
if it doesn’t you can run the `dhclient` to  get an IP address via DHCP.

The `dhclient` command ca be replaced with 2 `ip` commands:

```
ip addr add IP-ADDRESSE/24 dev wlan0
ip route add default via ROUTE
```

4. `iwctl` command line tools.

The [`iwd`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/iwd)  package provide the `iwctl` command line tools . The package isn't installed by default. To avoid any conflict the `wpasupplicant.service` should be stopped/disabled.

for more details see this answer on U&L: [Connect to wifi from command line on linux systems through the iwd (wireless daemon for linux)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477488/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line-on-linux-systems-through-the-iwd-wireless-dae)

**Further reading :**

[Connecting with wpa_cli](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli)

[Connecting with wpa_passphrase](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_passphrase)

[nmcli examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#nmcli_examples)

[Archlinux: iwd/iwctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd#iwctl)

Comment: your first solution is exactly like one in that tutorial, with one difference you create file by yourself, and there they used wpa_passphrase, but connecting via nmcli solved my problem, thanks

Comment: Please add for debian user of barebone arm system needs to add interface to `/etc/network/intefaces
auto wlp1s0
iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp
  pre-up wpa_supplicant -i wlp1s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B` Then rebooting little box and it has ip already...

Comment: I wonder if there is a "pseudogui" available. When I setup the box, I was presented selection of ethernet or wifi. 
I selected wifi, then seleted SSID from a list, entered encryption, password, if I wanted dhcp or static IP, 
Then network worked to complete the installation.

Why isn't this setup which works for the setup copied to the final system? Why is all this cli nessecary?

Comment: nmtui is not available after install. Having to get online to get a gui to get online is a chicken-and-egg problem. I managed to save the /target/etc/network/interfaces during install; after install the lines for the wifi is removed.

Comment: this is outdated

Comment: nmcli worked for me in linux mint 19, where I didn't have wpa_supplicant.

Comment: @Stephen No, it should be installed by default during the system install.

Answer (score 3):

To install wpa_supplicant on Debian, type

```
sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

in the terminal. To create the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, type in

```
echo 'network={ssid="nameOfYourWiFiNetwork" psk="thePassword"}' >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: In my opinion the OP is a specific question and this is not an answer to it.

Comment: indeed,  the OP said "...and after running wpa supplicant with valid network details:

Comment: He was only missing the dhclient call.

Comment: dhclient call hang forever