# How do I get my wireless connection configured without an ethernet connection?

Tags: debian, wifi

Here's my issue and the setup:

- I have one laptop (we'll call it "A") with Debian 8-Cinnamon (32 bit) (specs not relevant here), which has a wireless internet connection and NO WAY to connect to a wired network, the physical RJ-45 port is destroyed.
- I have a second laptop (Lenovo G50-45; we'll call it "B".) running Debian 8-Cinnamon (64 bit), which has NO WAY to connect to a wired network (DON'T ask.), and no current wifi connection.

I need to get the wireless setup and configured on "B" by this route:

1. Determine files/packages/whatever TF you want to call them on "B";
2. Download whatever on "A";
3. Place files on USB thumbdrive in "A";
4. Put USB thumbdrive into "B";
5. Install/move/whatever files from thumbdrive onto "B";
6. Make wireless work.

   - I have downloaded the appropriate drivers (`firmware-realtek_0.43_all.deb`) and installed them via gdebi.
   - I have downloaded and installed the appropriate "wireless-tools" (`wireless-tools_30~pre9-8_amd64.deb`).
   - I downloaded "network manager" which I heard was needed to properly configure the wifi, but cannot install it because it is not a .deb file. It appears to be source code, containing info for ./configure and make, but when I try to `./configure` I get the error `"configure: error: Your intltool is too old. You need intltool 0.40.0 or later."` I have intltool 0.40.0 installed, and the latest intltool package on the debian website is 0.35.0, an older version.

HOW do I get the wireless working on the "B"?

Answer (score 3):

## Original

Maybe you can have a look over here:[How to connect to wifi from command line ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283722/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

It seems that NetworkManager is not necessary to configure wireless.

Maybe you want to install several Debian packages without internet connection to get things working. Please check over here for an explanation how to do that:[How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Those two answers will hopefully get your wireless up and running. Please let us know if this works out, or where you get stuck exactly.

## Edit

After you managed to install Debian by copying the full installation image to the laptop only the wifi problem is open.

A default driver for Debian for your wifi card is not supplied. However, a [specific driver can be found here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new). You can check [this video providing installation instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxV2znrQxTc) for your specific laptop model, those are based on Ubuntu, but should be largely the same on Debian.

Comment: Already an issue: Running command "sudo iw dev" returns nothing. 
lspci lists:
"01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0041 (rev 20)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)"

The driver package mentioned in my post states on Debian's website as well as within gdebi that it contains the wireless drivers needed, as well as the ethernet drivers, but am I missing something?

Comment: Note: the Keryx project in your second link no longer exists, and the domain has gone back to the host

Comment: I'm just downloading the Debian is with the non-free software and going to try it that way. I have some temporary brain trauma that is not allowing me to hold long enough strings in my working memory to calculate...? right now.  I will see if that works.

Comment: @Ben Try to install the [`firmware-atheros_20161130-2~bpo8+1_all.deb`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/all/firmware-atheros/download) then run `modprobe ath10k`

Comment: I am now having the issue "The 'grub-pc' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot." When I try to switch to the shell at F5, I cannot log in using the credentials i provided during the install.

Comment: Can't install lilo bootloader either, and when I try to continue without installing bootloader the system locks up and must be hard shut down. I have tried with 3 seperate (and checked md5 sum) downloads of debian, on 2 seperate usb thumbdrives.

Comment: @Ben Are you reinstalled the system and getting a warning ?

Comment: @GAD3R After making a bootable USB via the "cp" command instead of using UNETBOOTIN, I no longer have any installation problems at all. The WIFI problem ended up being because there is No specific firmware for my particular hardware, and so I had to install a newer kernel and exploit a glitch to use similar firmware for my hardware. I posted the IRC chat log of my conversation with the person who helped me in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Debian install just does not work via netbootin. The preferred way, I have discovered, is just to 'cp /DEBIAN.iso /dev/sdX' Where "/DEBIAN.iso" is the file path of the Debian iso, and "/dev/sdX" is the path of your USB device, in my instance was /dev/sdb.

The whole process for getting the wifi to work on a Lenovo g50-45 is complicated, but required installing a new Kernel and exploiting a glitch for another firmware. Here is the IRC chat log in which the process (that I still don't understand, or I would have edited it and posted it here):
http://pastebin.com/yD4RT48P