# How does debian-installer configure WiFi during installation?

Tags: wifi, debian-installer

I am building Raspberry Pi images using the [raspi3-image-spec](https://github.com/Debian/raspi3-image-spec) project. Since it isn't the result of a conventional `d-i` installation, it obviously neither asks nor configures the root with WiFi information to connect on boot.

As such, I would like to know how exactly `d-i` stores WiFi details and makes it so it automatically connects when booted for the first time. I want to do the same on my RPi image, so that I don't have to connect to Ethernet or keyboard and monitor to configure its WiFi connectivity.

> I am not asking how to connect to WiFi using commands, I already know how
>   to do that. All I am asking is how the preconfiguration is done by
>   `d-i`.
>
> Per @kemotep's solution, not only do I
>   have to run a command to connect to WiFi, I have to manually activate
>   the `dhcpd`, or assign a static IP address. I also know how to
>   automate these steps using `/etc/network/interfaces` file, but that's beside the point.
>
> What I want to know is how `d-i` does it, so it conforms to regular
>   Debian installs and my WiFi configuration files are not
>   accidentally deleted during updates and the like.

Comment: I removed the `raspberry-pi` tag because neither `d-i` nor the WiFi configuration has anything to do with the device itself. I only mentioned as context of the question.

Comment: @Goro, why'd you quote the edits?

Comment: Ah, as a way of highlighting? I thought the header would be enough to draw attention to new info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Issue at Hand

You wish to know how to set up `debian-installer` to pre-configure your WiFi settings. You mention using [this build](https://github.com/Debian/raspi3-image-spec) to create an image of Debian for a Raspberry Pi 3.

They are using `debootstrap` and not the standard `debian-installer` to install Debian on the Raspberry Pi. I will provide information on how to pre-configure your WiFi using both processes.

## Using `debian-installer`

If you wish to know how individual components of `debian-installer` works please read over [this manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster//amd64/). Section 6.3.1.5 covers configuring the network. [Section 3.3.4](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster//amd64/ch03s03.en.html) helps provide information about what you will need to provide to `debian-installer` to set up networking.

However, all of this is a manual process that can be automated via "preseeding" or providing `debian-installer` with a pre-configuration file.

Here is the [Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso) on how to edit a preseed file. I am also include [another manual page](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apbs04.html.en) to help provide additional information on preseeding.

[Here is an example preseed.cfg](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/example-preseed.txt) for you to look over. Edit it to include the steps to add wireless firmware ( `d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true` is the key line here ).

Add these lines to preseed a wireless WPA2 network to your `preseed.cfg` after you have added the lines to load your firmware. [Check here for information on how to load firmware during `debian-installer`](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch06s04.html.en)

```
d-i netcfg/wireless_essid [string] // Name of wireless network
d-i netcfg/wireless_security_type [select] // Options are wep/open or wpa
d-i netcfg/wireless_wpa [string] // Password
```

[Here is a fairly comprehensive list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2012/09/msg00235.html) to show you possible `netcfg` options. Add more as needed to your `preseed.cfg` if the ones I listed do not cut it. Once you have created your `preseed.cfg` add it in using the following steps.

To add a preseed file you will need to mount your `debian.iso` and extract the the contents to copy in your `preseed.cfg`. The [arch] refers to the architecture of your `.iso`. In your case it is most likely `armhf` or `arm64`.

```
udevil mount debian.iso
cp -rT /media/debian.iso/ isofiles/
chmod +w -R isofiles/install.[arch]/
gunzip isofiles/install.[arch]/initrd.gz
echo preseed.cfg | cpio -H newc -o -A -F isofiles/install.[arch]/initrd
gzip isofiles/install.386/initrd
chmod -w -R isofiles/install.[arch]/
```

Here is how you fix md5sum.txt:

```
# cd isofiles
# md5sum `find -follow -type f` > md5sum.txt
# cd ..
```

Here is how you create a new bootable ISO image:

```
genisoimage -r -J -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat \                                                    
            -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \                                                           
            -o preseed-debian.iso isofiles
```

Now you have created a bootable ISO image to be written to your installer USB or disk that contains your pre-configurations. Make sure to read over [the Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso) and [the manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apbs04.html.en) carefully to help troubleshoot any issues.

## Using `debootstrap`

Another method of installing Debian is to use `debootstrap`. [Here is a link to the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) and another [link to the manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/debootstrap/debootstrap.8.en.html). `Debootstrap` can be used to create an installation of Debian from an existing Unix or Linux machine.

Using `debootstrap` only requires a `chroot` or other disk/partitions and a network connection to download the packages from the repository. You can then `chroot` into the new Debian `rootfs` and configure it as needed then propagate it out to any device you wish the install to be on. This is very similar to the Arch Linux install process.

However, if you are using [this script from GitHub](https://github.com/Debian/raspi3-image-spec), and you wish to pre-stage your wireless configuration then you will need to edit `raspi3.yaml` and use `vmdb2`.

Install `vmdb2`: ( This assumes you are using Debian Stretch! )

```
 apt install kpartx parted qemu-utils qemu-user-static python3-cliapp \
 python3-jinja2 python3-yaml
```

> Note that `python3-cliapp` is not available in Stretch, but as it does not carry any dependencies, can be manually installed by [fetching its .deb package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3-cliapp) and installing it manually.

Next download a copy of the image:

```
 git clone --recursive https://github.com/Debian/raspi3-image-spec
 cd raspi3-image-spec
```

Now edit the `raspi3.yaml` to include the following:

After `- apt: install` on line 68 add these lines:

```
- iw
```

Now after line 90 ( `- shell: |` ) you can add this code on its own line:

```
wpa_passphrase [WiFi SSID] [WiFI Password] > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

As long as `wpa_supplicant` installs correctly during your image process this line should add your WiFi configuration to allow you to connect automatically. You will still need to probably run these commands after boot, but they could potentially be added to the script too.

```
ip link set wlan0 down
ip link set wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
dhclient wlan0
```

> Once you have edited `raspi3.yaml`, you can generate the image by issuing the following. If you are using the systemwide `vmdb2`:
>
> ```
> umask 022
> sudo env -i LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 PATH="/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH" \
> vmdb2 --output raspi3.img raspi3.yaml --log raspi3.log
> ```
>
> Or, if you are using it from the submodule in this repository
>
> ```
> umask 022
> sudo env -i LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 PATH="/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH" \
> ./vmdb2/vmdb2 --output raspi3.img raspi3.yaml --log raspi3.log
> ```

After that you should be able to install the new image onto an SD card and it will follow the extra steps you added in the script. You can add any additional steps you wish to the file.

The [OP of this stack exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283722/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line) noted that the second method user GAD3R advises works as well to add wireless configurations via command line.

## Conclusion

If you are using `debian-installer` you will need to preseed your `debian.iso` with the configuration you desire.

If you are using `debootstrap` you will have to include any additional steps you wish to take in the installation process or `chroot` in afterwards.

I will be including the [Debian Wiki Page](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi) on WiFi as well as [the How To page](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) and the information on [adding missing firmware](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster//amd64/ch06s04.en.html). The wireless firmware can be found [here for Raspberry Pi](https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/f/firmware-nonfree/)

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through each link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!

Comment: It is my fault that I was not explicit in my question, but I'm aware how to connect using command prompts, using precisely the commands you answered with. My aim of the question was to let RPi connect to WiFi so that I don't have to attach a keyboard and screen to it and remotely `ssh` into it. Adding the `wpapassphrase` file will not let it connect to WiFi automatically either, hence your answer is moot anyway.

Comment: @Oxwivi To correct my answer, are you wishing to know in general how `debian-installer` configures WiFi? If I am reading the script from GitHub correctly you are not using `debian-installer` but taking an image of Debian and running the commands from the `raspi3.yaml` to build it on the Raspberry Pi. Or are you using [this installer](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/armhf/iso-cd/) and not the scripts? I think that is where I am confused. I can edit my post accordingly to satisfy that requirement. I left the 2nd part in for others who may not know how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the GitHub script, and I wish to know how `d-i` does it in general to use it on the image created by the script. It's literally the title: "How does debian-installer confugre WiFi"

Comment: @Oxwivi Thank you for clarifying. The GitHub page you linked uses `qemu-debootstrap` and not `debian-installer`. It appears that `debian-installer` uses `NetworkManager` but can also be preseeded to include certain configurations. I can edit my post to reflect this but if you are using the GitHub script you linked to that will not help you.

Comment: There isn't anything stopping me from modifying the `.img` file after it has been generated. Other than that, is there anyway to run `d-i` in the `qemu-debootstrap` environment?

Comment: And yes, please edit your answer to show that.

Comment: @Oxwivi I have updated my answer. Please review it to see if it provides better information for you.

Comment: The "this manual" link seems to be dead

Comment: @lucidbrot all the more reason to make sure to put the relevant content in the post and not to just link out. Not sure if I will be able to find that information again but I will try.

Comment: Great that you have linked to many sources. The [ubiquity repo](https://github.com/GalliumOS/ubiquity/blob/master/d-i/source/netcfg/debian/netcfg-common.templates) lists the options available whereas the debian docs only seem to give examples of the most frequently used ones. [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/) also makes preseeding much easier as there is no need to modify boot images or setup a netboot PXE server, however I'm not sure it works with RPi??