# Connect to wifi from command line on linux systems through the iwd (wireless daemon for linux)

Tags: wifi, iwlwifi, iw, iwd

The [`iwd`](https://iwd.wiki.kernel.org/) is the up-and-coming wireless daemon for linux released by
Intel and the wpasupplicant successor. The development of iwd is still in [progress](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/about/), but it is packaged under some linux distribution  Gentoo, Arch-linux , Ubuntu (Cosmic) and [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager/iwd) ([Buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/iwd) and Sid)...

The configuration of the network and the connection is possible through the interactive mode using `iwctl` , the help command will display the list of the available commands (no manpage ).

Without using the interactive mode :

1. How can I manually configure the wifi credentials?
2. How can I connect to the configured wifi through `iwctl`?
3. How can I automatically enable the wifi connection at boot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) From the non-interactive mode , you can scan and list the available access points :

```
iwctl station wlp8s0 scan
iwctl station wlp8s0 get-networks
```

The wifi credentials are stored under `/var/lib/iwd` , the exact name of the SSID should be used , the format:

```
SSID.psk
```

The content:

```
[Security]
PreSharedKey=encripted-password
Passphrase=the-plain-txt-password
```

The minimal configuration file should contain the encrypted wifi paswword (PreSharedKey)

To generate an encrypted psk , you can use the wpa_passhrase tool:

```
wpa_passhrase "My-SSID" passphrase
```

There is an example using "My SSID" and `mysecretpassword`:

```
$ cat My\ SSID.psk
[Security]
PreSharedKey=8e1e64a6ecaf2b5e0aa29816547af300d7f3b0473bbfa56ddb5514ad4683804c
```

2) To connect from the terminal:

```
iwctl station <INTERFACE> connect "SSID"
```

e,g:

```
iwctl station wlp8s0 connect "My SSID"
dhclient
```

`dhclient` can be replaced an iproute2 command to assign an IP address to wlp8s0.

3) to automatically enable the wifi connection at boot , there is a way using a systemd service:

A minimal script to connect:

```
$ cat /usr/local/enable-wifi.sh

#!/bin/bash
iwctl station wlan0 connect "My SSID" 
dhclient
```

Create a systemd service.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/enable-wifi.service

[Unit]
Before=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/enable-wifi.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

then :

```
# chmod 744 /usr/local/enable-wifi.sh
# chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/enable-wifi.service
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable enable-wifi.service
```

documentation:

arch-linux wiki : [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd)

Debian wiki: [NetworkManager/iwd](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager/iwd)

lwn: [iwd: simplifying WiFi management](https://lwn.net/Articles/770991/)

Comment: The way I understand it PreSharedKey is an encrypted version of Passphrase. And if there's PreSharedKey Passphrase is not needed. If that is so, there must be somewhere an encryption key to decrypt PreSharedKey?