# How can I have iwd connect automatically to known and available WiFi?

Tags: systemd, wifi, iwd

On my Archlinux I'm currently connecting to the internet via WiFi using `iwctl`. Everytime I boot, I run `iwctl` and then `station wlan0 connect WIFINAME`.

How can I have the connection happen automatically?

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477490/164309) suggests to create a systemd service which basically runs the command I wrote above. (It also runs `dhclient`, but I have to look up what it does.)

However the Archlinux wikipage on [iwd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd) reads

> `iwd` automatically stores network passphrases in the `/var/lib/iwd` directory and uses them to auto-connect in the future. See [#Network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iwd#Network_configuration).

which seems to mean that the auto-connection feature should be automatic. However it isn't for me.

- What might be preventing the autoconnection to work?
- Is setting a systemd service the only way to get it working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found some help on ArchLinux' IRC channel, and I'm sharing it in this self answer.

To make `iwd` automatically connect to WiFis, is enough to have

```
[Settings]
AutoConnect=true
```

in the `/etc/iwd/main.conf` file, as long as the config file specific to the WiFi we want to automatically connect to, e.g. `/var/lib/iwd/whatever.psk`, doesn't override that with `AutoConnect=false`.

The `AutoConnect=true` setting should be the default; I don't know why, but it was not the case for me, as all `/var/lib/iwd/*.psk` files had `AutoConnect=false` in them.