# How to connect with wifi in void linux from scratch

Tags: linux, system-installation, void-linux, runit

The instalation of void linux , without desktop manager, it's come without `Network-Manager` package,

- so i can't use `nmtui` and `iwctl` as arch linux.
- also void linix it's not support `system.d` , it's runit system
- what's the better why to connect to wifi in first time:

Comment: See the first link in my answer.

Comment: Updating with the same content of the answer, discouraging people from answering your questions next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- First, you must create the correct configuration using `wpa_passphrase` (do not confused `wpa_passphrase` and `wpa_supplicant`):

```
$ wpa_passphrase "wifi-name" "password" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

- Then, find your device name (like `wlan0`), by executing

```
$ ip link
```

- Start `wpa-supplicant`, but change `wlan0` to *your* device name

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

- Finally, link service to `runit` by

```
# ln -s /etc/sv/wpa_supplicant /var/service
```

To test your connection, you can try

```
$ ping wikipedia.org
```

When you reboot your machine, the connection configuration will be lost. You would have to run `wpa-supplicant` again. Alternatively, you can add the following line to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (for `zsh` add to `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc`; for `~/.xnitrc`, add with `&` at the end):

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to WPA/WPA2, you need to install the [`wpa_supplicant`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant) or [`iwd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd).

Here is how to connect to wifi from cli (Answers on U&L):

- [using `wpasupplicant`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283757/153195)
- [using iwctl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477490/153195)

To use `nmcli` or `nmtui`, you need to install the NetworkManager package.

Comment: i get some answer from arch wiki and boid docs , the main problem how connect in first time

Answer (score 0):

Like if you want to use network manager and just chroot into ur void after installation and install network manager and when you log in you can use nmtui. I personally use connman and iwd