# Unable to connect to internet using iwd standalone

Tags: linux, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, iwd

I’m trying to connect to WiFi using `iwd` **standalone**, without `NetworkManager` or `wpa_supplicant`.

This is on a Debian 10 machine, with a `netinst` installation and no desktop environment.
I added the non-free component to `apt-sources` and installed `firmware-iwlwifi`.

I’ve modified `/etc/iwd/main.conf` as follows

```
[General]
EnableNetworkConfiguration=true

[Network]
NameResolvingService=systemd
```

I used `iwctl` to connect:

```
[iwd]# station list
                            Devices in Station Mode                           *
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                State          Scanning
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlp2s0              connected

[iwd]# device list
                                    Devices
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                Address             Powered   Adapter   Mode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlp2s0              xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   on        phy0      station
```

These are the running services:

```
UNIT                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
cron.service              loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon
dbus.service              loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
getty@tty1.service        loaded active running Getty on tty1
iwd.service               loaded active running Wireless service
rsyslog.service           loaded active running System Logging Service
ssh.service               loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server
systemd-journald.service  loaded active running Journal Service
systemd-logind.service    loaded active running Login Service
systemd-networkd.service  loaded active running Network Service
systemd-resolved.service  loaded active running Network Name Resolution
systemd-timesyncd.service loaded active running Network Time Synchronization
systemd-udevd.service     loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager
user@0.service            loaded active running User Manager for UID 0

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

13 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

The driver is loaded:

```
lspci | grep -i intel
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
```

I don’t see any errors here:

```
[    4.807336] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.330505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    9.815999] wlp2s0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[    9.825148] wlp2s0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[    9.868608] wlp2s0: authenticated
[    9.870031] wlp2s0: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[    9.874042] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=2)
[    9.877212] wlp2s0: associated
[    9.976363] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[   11.900982] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

But I’m not able to ping any address / hostname.

Is this related to `dhcpcd`?

Any ideas?

Relevant: [Connect to wifi from command line on linux systems through the iwd (wireless daemon for linux)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477488/connect-to-wifi-from-command-line-on-linux-systems-through-the-iwd-wireless-dae)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to Bullseye.