# debian minimal net install wifi setup terminal

Tags: debian, wifi

installed minimal debian stretch on t430s. installed the respective iwlwifi drivers. however i am unable to setup a wifi connection. need to download desktop env. XFCE

read following [link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283722/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line) [link2](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/18/connect-to-wifi-network-from-command-line-in-linux/)

in link 1 `ip link show` returns `lo<LOOPBACK>, enpos25<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>, wlp3so<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>`
in link 2 my system doesnt have the other utilities `wpa_applicant, iw`

what are the steps to setup the wifi connection?

Comment: You have to find a build compatible, check the version of CPU you have (AMD/&Intel (always OSx)) , if it doesn't work you need to find the drivers you have, otherwise just plug it in with an ethernet.

Comment: i have used amd64. sure its correct because this machine i am using now is the same and installed with xfce iso . no ethernet connection available.

Answer (score 1):

1) Change the wifi security from WPA/WPA2 to WEP of your access point AP.

2) Connect to the AP:

Download and install   [`libiw30`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libiw30) and [`wireless-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wireless-tools).

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "AP_here" key "s:password_here"    
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
dhclient wlan0
route add default gw GATWAY_HERE
ping -c2 8.8.8.8 # ping test
```

3) Install the [`wpa_supplicant`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/wpasupplicant) package :

```
apt update
apt install wpasupplicant
```

(`network-manager` package is useful, allowing you to connect through `nmcli` command line )

4) Change the security settings of your access point to WPA/WPA2. Using the `wpa_supplicant` you will be able to connect to an AP protect with WPA/WPA2.

[man iwconfig](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/wireless-tools/iwconfig.8.en.html)