# How can I make a LAN with a wifi adapter in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I am not interested in sharing internet connection, I just want to make an AP that multiple devices can connect to and communicate with each other.

I have a USB wifi adapter. How can I configure it to act as an AP.

No need for internet connection just a LAN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to wifi from command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283722/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

> AP without Internet sharing:
>
> ```
> create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
> ```

**Installation:**

You should install the dependencies :

> ```
> bash (to run this script)
> util-linux (for getopt)
> procps or procps-ng
> hostapd
> iproute2
> iw
> iwconfig (you only need this if 'iw' can not recognize your adapter)
> haveged (optional)
> dnsmasq
> iptables
> ```

Then:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

`create_ap` is packaged for gentoo and archlinux.

Comment: Do i install it with apt?

Comment: Ohh i see. Thank you.