# Debian 10: rfkill not found anywhere, still blocking my wifi

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, system-installation, debian-installer

I can find 'rfkill' in '/dev'. But, can't use it. I have no internet connection on my device. RF-KILL is so powerful that, **I can't even power on my WiFi interface from Winodws by any means!!!!**

I tried

```
ip link set wlp2s0 up
```

but it is still not working.

I am running standard Debian 10, so no GUI.

Comment: Could you add the output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3`.

Comment: @GAD3R [Thanks for reaching out again. Please help me out of this]                    Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Aethors AR9285 wireless network adapter (PCI-EXPRESS) [168c:002b]

Comment: You are welcome, run `sudo modprobe -rv ath9k` then `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`. then `sudo iw wlp2s0 scan |grep SSID` to check the APs. Are you able to list of the wifi AP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 0.  Using debian-standard iso? That's the culprit with literally nothing of networking. Connecting to internet is near to the border of 'impossible'.

*Suggestions*:     **debian-netinst.iso**. You will need internet for installation. It has some networking packages pre-installed. So, you may connect to WiFi without trouble, better with a desktop environment. But you will need to use your ethernet, as I needed, if installed without any desktop environment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe this is the closest we can get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put it here since I found the solution so I won't forget about it again.

So first, use `sudo ip link show` to show your wifi name

```
user@user:/$ sudo ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu ... qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode
...
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu ... qdisc noqueue state UP
...
```

For example, my wifi name is `wlp1s0`. What you need to do is to search with `sudo find /sys/ -name "wifi_name"`

```
user@user:/$ sudo find /sys/ -name "wlp1s0"
/sys/class/net/wlp1s0
/sys/devices/pci_random_id/random_id/random_id/net/wlp1s0
```

After that, search a directory with name `phy80211` or similar(name might vary depend on the device, since I'm new to this fix) inside `/sys/class/net/wlp1s0/`. Then, try to check inside of that directory with `ls`

```
user@user:/$ sudo ls /sys/class/net/wlp1s0/
...  ...  ...  phy80211  ...  ...  ...
user@user:/$ sudo ls /sys/class/net/wlp1s0/phy80211
addresses  address_mask  device  index  macaddress  name  power  rfkill3  subsystem  uevent
```

You can see that there's a folder called `rfkill3`. Then, try to check if rfkill3 is soft locked or not with cat. If it returns 1, that means the wifi soft locked and if returns 0, it's not soft locked.

```
user@user:/$ sudo cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill3/soft
1
```

When it's soft locked , try to modify it with

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill3/soft
```

or

```
sudo nano /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill3/soft
```

and change it to `0` if `echo` doesn't work. It might say `[ Error writing lock file /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill3/.soft.swp: Permission denied ]`, but during my fix, when I use nano as root/with sudo, it still able to modify the file and keep the change during that session despite the warning. But also, do not reboot the device for now since the soft lock will reset back to 1 if you do.

After changed the soft lock to 0, try activate it with `ip link set wifi_name up`, the wifi should be active now.

I suggest you to install `rfkill` and every networking tool you need after the fix(such as `network-manager` and etc) to make it easier to manage the networking. I hope this will help people who needed it.

Comment: Great answer, even if it is for your personal memory.  Please continue to learn from us and pass it on.  Welcome to the Exchange

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install any package, the free wireless driver `ath9k`  is introduced in Linux since the `2.6.27` kernel version.

To list wifi APs:

```
sudo iw wlp2s0 scan |grep SSID
```

To connect:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -iwlp2s0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "Your_SSID" Your_passphrase) && sudo dhclient wlp2s0
```

To make a persistent configuration see step1: [How to connect to wifi from command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283722/how-to-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

to solve the *WLAN hard blocked device* problem, download [libsmartcols1](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libsmartcols1/download) and [rfkill](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/rfkill/download) to your home directory then run:

```
sudo dpkg -i libsmartcols1_2.33.1-0.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i rfkill_2.33.1-0.1_amd64.deb
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: sudo: rfkill: command not found

Comment: I have no internet connection

Comment: 'No such file or directory' in both cases. I'm running without any form of GUI.

Comment: command failed: Network is down (-100)

Comment: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant    rfkill:WLAN hard blocked    n180211: deini ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0   wlp2s0: Failed to initialise driver interface